# How to calculate First time pass rate in Azure devops dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, analytics, dashboard, azure-analysis-services

The test cases are being maintained in Azure Dev ops, we want to create a Dashboard report for First time pass rate of the test cases executed in each sprint.

e.g Sprint 1

Test case 1: Run 1 - Fail | Run 2 - Pass
Test case 2: Run 1 - Pass

In this scenario, First time pass rate for Sprint 1 is 50%.

we want to create a dashboard report to calculate this after every sprint. Pls let us know if there is mechanism for this.